# Find the values of $p$ where two lines intersect

Tags: geometry, polynomials

I have the following to equations: $-2x+py-33=0$ and $8px+(p-1)y-11=0$
Find the values of $p$ where the two lines intersect.

My original plan was to figure out the slope for both lines with respect to $p$ and the figure out when they are equal, which gives me the only possible value where these lines don't intersect. This didn't work out as I couldn't solve for a single variable. The closest I got was to solving for $p$ which was dependent only on $x$, but the value I got for $x$ was dependent on both $p$ and $y$.

Comment: Find the intersection $(x,y)$ as a function of $p$, say $x=p/(p^2-1)$ and $y=p^2+p$ (this are just examples at random, not the actual solution). At that point you can study where this intersection exists. So you start by  solving  for $x$ and $y$ treating $p$ like it is a constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proceeding in your way, of comparing the slopes, we get
$$-2x+py-33=0 \Rightarrow y=\frac{2}{p}x+\frac{33}{p}$$
and 
$$8px+(p-1)y-11=0 \Rightarrow y=\frac{8p}{1-p}x+\frac{11}{p-1}$$

The lines will intersect always except when the slopes of the lines are equal, i.e. $$\frac{2}{p}=\frac{8p}{1-p}$$
$$2-2p=8p^2$$
$$8p^2+2p-2=0$$
$$4p^2+p-1=0$$

The roots of this quadratic equation are $p=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1+16}}{8}=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{17}}{8}$

So the lines intersect for all $p \in \mathbb{R}-\{\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{17}}{8}\}$.

Comment: Of course, I created the equation using the entire polynomial instead of the slope which had other variables aside from $p$. Thank you for this detailed answer.

Comment: @imas145 You're welcome.

Comment: @Logophobic Thanks for your help. :-)